# onClick method is not invoked, Reactjs, Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, callback, onclick

`addItem()` method which is bind to `onClick` event of the button is not invoked

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddItem extends Component{ 

     constructor(props:any){
            super(props);
            this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
        }

        addItem(){
            console.log("This is not working");
        }

        render(){
            return (
                <form>
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
                    <button onClick = {this.addItem}>Add</button>
                </form>
            )
        }
}
```

Comment: try clicking on the button and look at the console :)

Comment: I am doing it :) and the scenario is the same as I said

Comment: why are you using public?

Comment: @RedBaron I was just trying, but I changed it

Comment: addItem() function run when you click on the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [prevent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) default form event

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-wing-mbp65?file=/src/App.js)

```
addItem(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("This is not working");
}
```

Comment: @husnu I attached sandbox, change it to your not working example please

Comment: thank you for your help, I was using typescript and the solution is a little different from yours, but the idea is to use preventDefault() method. My solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62472406/9851619

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can do this.

```
{console.log("Reset Button", value)}
```

for details [desctiption](https://onecompiler.com/posts/3uvszjsdr/how-where-to-use-console-log-in-react-jsx)

Answer (score 0):

Working fine

```js
class AddItem extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
  }

  addItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("This is not working");
  }

  render() {
    console.log("This is working")
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < AddItem / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the inspiration to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62466708/9851619
(Author : @NikitaMadeev)

I just needed to configure the answer in this link according to typescript because I am using it.(the code below is in a file named **AddItem.tsx**)

`MouseEvent` interface is used and `preventDefault()` method is invoked, then the problem is solved..

Thanks for everyone who efforts to solve the issue.

```
import React, { Component, MouseEvent } from 'react';

class AddItem extends Component{ 
    ...
    ...
    ...
    addItem(event:MouseEvent) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("After preventDefault, this function is started working");
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <form>
                ...
                ...
                ...
                <button onClick = {this.addItem}>Add</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Tried it on CodePen, you have to remove the "public" statement, in this case it is not useful, and it makes your code not working

Comment: It did not work YanvegHd, thanks for your effort to help